# SQL aggregation by value of single column

Tags: sql, group-by, count, case

Let’s assume I have a table like this:

| Id | url |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11.22.33 |
| 2 | 11.22.33 |
| 3 | domain.com |
| 4 | domain2.com |
| 5 | domain.com |
| 6 | 10.100.15 |
| 7 | domain3.com |
| 8 | 172.100.15 |
| 9 | 172.100.15 |

In this table, some IP addresses are associated with some domains and we can consider them being single URL. (For example, domain2.com, 10.100.15, 11.22.33 - it's domain2.com; 172.100.15, domain3.com - domain3.com, etc). My task is that I have to calculate rows with different domains and make a table like this:

| url | count |
| --- | --- |
| domain2 | 4 |
| domain | 2 |
| domain3 | 2 |

I could just count them with several queries, such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1
WHERE (table1.url = “10.100.15”
    OR table1.url = “11.22.33” OR table1.url = “domain2.com”)
```

and make this table manually but it’s not cool.

How could I do it in a single query?

**PS**: as mentioned in the comment below, usual aggregation could be done with one simple query:

```
SELECT url, count(*) 
FROM table1
WHERE GROUP BY url
```

But it gives me only the table like this:

| URL | count |
| --- | --- |
| domain2 | 1 |
| domain | 2 |
| 11.22.33 | 2 |
| 10.100.15 | 1 |

Or am I missing something?

Comment: THe query in your question *is* a single query, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Without a rule that establishes somehow (via a self-referencing foreign key, for example) which ip addresses and domains belong together, you would have to hard-wire with `CASE WHEN` or a `WHERE` condition what belongs to what. How can I see just from the data - not from your text - what belongs to what? All preceding ip addresses to the following domain, for example?

Comment: @ 
marcothesane 
You can't. Let's consider you only know hardcoded conditions.

Comment: You can use "in" operator like this: where table1.url in( “10.100.15” ,“11.22.33” , domain2.com)

Comment: @vahidrobati
 Ok. And then what? It just gives me counting only by domain2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN URL IN ('10.100.15', '11.22.33', 'domain2.com') THEN 'domain2.com'
         WHEN URL IN ('172.100.15', 'domain3.com') THEN 'domain3.com'
         ELSE URL
       END domain,
       COUNT(*) count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY domain;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3452dde1c0654b0b057671815823ad4d).

Comment: Cool! Thank you! Just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way is to have the association stored in the database to achieve that:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(Id,url) AS (
          SELECT 1,'11.22.33'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'11.22.33'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'domain.com'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'domain2.com'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'domain.com'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'10.100.15'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'domain3.com'
UNION ALL SELECT 8,'172.100.15'
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'172.100.15'
)
,
-- need an association table - which "url" belongs to which domain
assoc(dom,url) AS (
            SELECT 'domain2.com','10.100.15'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'domain2.com','11.22.33'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'domain3.com','172.100.15'
)
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN a.dom IS NULL THEN i.url
    ELSE a.dom
  END AS domain
, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM indata AS i
LEFT
JOIN assoc  AS a USING(url)
GROUP BY domain
;

-- out
-- out    domain    | counter
-- out -------------+---------
-- out  domain2.com |       4                                                                                                                                                                             
-- out  domain3.com |       3
-- out  domain.com  |       2
-- out (3 rows)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a clever approach, though a bit redundant in my case. Anyway, thank you! It might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use group by function and write your code like this:

SELECT URL, count(*)
from table1
where URL in('domain1','domain2')
group by (URL)

it will work!

Comment: No, it's not. This gives me counting by every URL. I have to combine some rows that assign to ONE domain.